# Sorting logic and generation of letter sequence

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, sorting

In the context of experimental designs, it is common to generate the various treatment names to build the factorial design table.

The table of the 2^2 design reads :

[image: 2^2 Design table]

For the 2^3, the table reads :

[image: 2^3 Design table]

And for 2^4 :

[image: 2^4 Design table]

I would like to generate such table for the general case 2^k. Here is what I've done so far :

```
FactorialDesign[k_] := Module[{D, Factor, combinations, Treatments},
   D = Reverse[Tuples[{-1, 1}, k], 2];
   Factor = Table[FromLetterNumber[i], {i, 1, k}];
   combinations = Subsets[Factor];
   Treatments = 
   Table[StringJoin[combination], {combination, combinations}];
   Treatments[[1]] = "(1)";
   Join[Transpose@{Treatments}, D, 2]
]
```

In the case of the 2^3 design, the function yields :

```
FactorialDesign[3]
(*{{"(1)", -1, -1, -1}, {"a", 1, -1, -1}, {"b", -1, 1, -1}, {"c", 1, 
1, -1}, {"ab", -1, -1, 1}, {"ac", 1, -1, 1}, {"bc", -1, 1, 
1}, {"abc", 1, 1, 1}}*)
```

As you will see, the (-1) and (1) matrix matches with the examples I've provided, but not the treatments. They follow an other order {a,b,ab,c,ac,bc,abc} for the ^3 case.

Firstly, I'd be interested in understanding the mathematical logic (if any) behind the way the treatments are ordered in these examples. And then to be able to correct my code to generate arrays for 2^k-case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be considerably easier to create the treatment strings from the design tuples. That way they stay synchronized. Here is one way to do that.

```
factorialDesign[k_] := 
 Module[{designs, factors, combinations, treatments}, 
  designs = Reverse[Tuples[{-1, 1}, k], 2];
  factors = Table[FromLetterNumber[i], {i, 1, k}];
  combinations = 
   Table[(designs[[j]] + 1)/2*factors, {j, Length[designs]}] /. 
    0 -> Nothing;
  treatments = Map[StringJoin, combinations];
  treatments[[1]] = "(1)";
  Join[Transpose@{treatments}, designs, 2]]

In[604]:= factorialDesign[4]

(* Out[604]= {{"(1)", -1, -1, -1, -1}, {"a", 1, -1, -1, -1}, {"b", -1, 
  1, -1, -1}, {"ab", 1, 1, -1, -1}, {"c", -1, -1, 1, -1}, {"ac", 
  1, -1, 1, -1}, {"bc", -1, 1, 1, -1}, {"abc", 1, 1, 
  1, -1}, {"d", -1, -1, -1, 1}, {"ad", 1, -1, -1, 1}, {"bd", -1, 
  1, -1, 1}, {"abd", 1, 1, -1, 1}, {"cd", -1, -1, 1, 1}, {"acd", 
  1, -1, 1, 1}, {"bcd", -1, 1, 1, 1}, {"abcd", 1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

If you are new to the language the tactic of creating `combinations` might seem...obscure. Not to worry, there are other ways to go about it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which solves my problem. I'm still having a bit of trouble understanding how I can get the combination of factors in the order I want from the `Subsets` function. Apparently it is possible to generate power sets in this order using binary sorting (ref : Representing subsets as functions -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set ). But for now I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

To understand the order, let us take the output of "FactorialDesign[3]":

```
{{"(1)", -1, -1, -1}, {"a", 1, -1, -1}, {"b", -1, 1, -1}, {"c", 1, 
1, -1}, {"ab", -1, -1, 1}, {"ac", 1, -1, 1}, {"bc", -1, 1, 
1}, {"abc", 1, 1, 1}}
```

and delete the treatment names and replace "-1" by zero:

```
dat = {{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, -1, 
    1}, {1, -1, 1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}} /. -1 -> 0

{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {0,
   1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}
```

You may alreaday see what is going on, but let us make it explicit by interpret them as binary digits, going from lower to higher:

```
FromDigits[Reverse@#, 2] & /@ dat

{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Now it is clear, the order is binary counting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Now do you see any solution for sorting the treatments in the same way as the matrix D is sorted ? Such that `Treatments = {a,b,ab,c,ac,bc,abc}` and not `Treatments = {"a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc"}`

Comment: You may sort e.g.:`dat={{"(1)", -1, -1, -1}, {"a", 1, -1, -1}, {"b", -1, 1, -1}, {"c", 1, 1, -1}, {"ab", -1, -1, 1}, {"ac", 1, -1, 1}, {"bc", -1, 1, 1}, {"abc", 1, 1, 1}}`  by using "SortBy": `SortBy[dat, FromDigits[Reverse[#[[2 ;;]] /. -1 -> 0], 2] &]`

Answer (score 3):

Just another way to generate the factorial design table:

```
factorialDesign[k_] :=
  Map[{Splice@#, StringJoin@Pick[Alphabet[][[;; k]], #, 1] /. "" -> "(1)"} &
  , SortBy[Tuples[{-1, 1}, k], FromDigits[Reverse@#, 2] &] ]
```

Show table:

```
TableForm[factorialDesign[#] /. {-1 -> "-", 1 -> "+"}
, TableHeadings -> {None, {Splice@ToUpperCase@Alphabet[][[;; #]], "Label"}}] &[3]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just to participate:

```
func[a_, b_, alpha_] := Module[{u = Length[alpha], r, i, s},
  r = Range[0, 2^u - 1];
  i = Reverse /@ IntegerDigits[r, 2, u];
  s = Times @@ (alpha^#) & /@ i;
  TableForm[i /. {0 -> a, 1 -> b}, 
   TableHeadings -> {s[[r + 1]], alpha}, TableAlignments -> Right]]
```

So,

```
func[-1, 1, {a, b}]
func[-1, 1, {a, b, c}]
func["_", "+", {a, b, c, d}]
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
runlabels[n_] := 
 StringJoin @@@ Subsets[Characters@Alphabet[][[1 ;; n]]] /. 
  "" -> "(1)"
factors[n_] := 
 IntegerDigits[#, 2, n] &@Range[0, 2^n - 1] /. {0 -> "-", 1 -> "+"} //
   Map[Reverse]

With[{n = #},
   vars = Alphabet[][[1 ;; n]]; 
   Transpose[{factors[n], runlabels[n]}] // Flatten[#, {1}] & //
       Map[Flatten] //
      Prepend[#, {Sequence @@ ToUpperCase@vars, "RunLabel"}] & //
     Grid[
       Prepend[#, {"Factor", Sequence @@ Table[SpanFromLeft, {n - 1}],
          ""}]
       , Alignment -> {{{Center}, Right}, {Center, Center}}
       , ItemStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{1, 1} -> {14, Bold}}}
       , Background -> {None, {GrayLevel[0.9], Cyan}}
       , ItemSize -> {{Sequence @@ Table[SpanFromLeft, {n}], 5}, {2, 
          1, 1}}
       ] & // Framed
   ] & /@ Range[2, 5]
```